# Apply opacity for Grid and don't apply for its children Controls

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I apply **opacity** 0.75 for the `Grid` and all children which has `Grid` also take the **opacity**.

Is it possible **to exclude child Controls and don't apply opacity for them?**

Thank you!

**XAML**

```
<Grid  x:Name="RootGrid" Opacity="0.75" Visibility="Visible" ClipToBounds="False"
       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <local:MarqueeVer x:Name="marquee1" Duration="30" ClipToBounds="True"
                      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="Transparent" Opacity="1">
        <StackPanel Name="lstItems" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Vertical"
                    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
        </StackPanel>
    </local:MarqueeVer>
</Grid>
```

**UPDATE:**

I found some solution [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/252301/630133.aspx/1?Opacity%20effect%20on%20child%20control) but is any simpler solution?

> You just have to calculate the right alpha channel for each color.

Comment: Can you post here your xaml code for a better understanding?

Comment: @EduardoBrites Sure. It is there. Please have a look.

Comment: Why do you want to set the opacity of the grid itself?  Grid is generally just used for layout, and isn't visible.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650576/how-do-you-override-the-opacity-of-a-parent-control-in-wpf

Comment: @Robaticus my grid takes background image, colors. So it is visible. I just need to apply opacity to Grid only and not to its child.

Comment: In your example, which controls do you NOT want to have the opacity changed?

Comment: If you only want to change the opacity of the grid's background, then you need to set the opacity=0.75 only in the background image.

Comment: @EduardoBrites Ok. I will try. But what I Apply some Brush to the Grid? WHat I can do in thhat case? Hmmm Perhapc I can create some BitmapImage and apply some Color and then opacity... Hmmm

Comment: In the that case set the opacity in the brush ;)

Comment: @EduardoBrites Put your comments like an answer I will mark it as an answer. It works for me! (+++)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want to change the opacity of the grid's background, then you need to set the opacity=0.75 only in the background image.

> But what I Apply some Brush to the Grid? WHat I can do in thhat case?

In the that case set the opacity in the brush

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this effect, you can add a `Rectangle` as a child of the `Grid` (but as a sibling to the other elements) and apply the `Background` and `Opacity` to the `Rectangle`. This way, the change of opacity doesn't affect the other children of the `Grid`.

```
<Grid Name="Root">
<Rectangle Name="Background" Opacity="0.75">
<Rectangle.Fill>

</Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
<Label>Hello World</Label>
</Grid>
```

I know this is probably a dirty solution, but it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make child more opaque than parent, but you can use brushes with different opacity, to achieve some overlay effects for example.

Like this:

```
<Window x:Class="stackoverflowviewbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity=".5" x:Key="WhiteHalfOpacityBrush"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="Green">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource WhiteHalfOpacityBrush}">
            <Label>
                Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```