# Set StackPanel opacity without affecting its children

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF. I have a `StackPanel` and in this stack panel, I've added a `TextBlock` and set stack panel's background and Text Block's foreground color, all in code behind. I also set opacity dynamicaly. Problem is, when I set opacity of stackpanel, it affects it's child controls (i.e Textblock).

Please give me a proper solution for this.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code you already have so we don't have to re tool what you've already done?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10636502/1025209

Answer (score 31):

If you want to do it in `Xaml`,  you can create a `SolidColorBrush` at your `Window.Resources` to be the background color of your panel:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TransparentBlue" Color="#00b0f0" Opacity="0.5" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And then only set the `Background` of your `...Panel`:

```
<StackPanel Background="{StaticResource TransparentBlue}">
    <Label Content="Hello there" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Label>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read the Remarks of [UIElement.Opacity Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Opacity is applied from parent elements on down the element tree to
>   child elements, but the visible effects of the nested opacity settings
>   aren't indicated in the property value of individual child elements.
>   For instance, if a list has a 50% (0.5) opacity and one of its list
>   items has its own opacity set to 20% (0.2), the net visible opacity
>   for that list item will be rendered as if it were 10% (0.1), but the
>   property value of the list item Opacity property would still be 0.2
>   when queried.

A child control can't have more opacity then parent. I think you will have to use two separate layers, one with full opacity and one with less. Something like this

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Opacity=".5" Background="whatever">
        ...
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Text shown with full Opacity" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Background` property to a mutable `Brush` (instead of an immutable like `Brushes.White`). You may for example create a `SolidColorBrush`:

```
var background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
panel.Background = background;
```

You may now change the `Opacity` property of that brush later on in your program.

```
background.Opacity = 0.5;
```

You may also do this with any other brush like `GradientBrush` or `ImageBrush` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Xamarin (White transparent color) :

```
Color MyColor = Color.FromRgba(255,255,255,0.8);
```

Alpha seems to give better opacity than the Opacity property of controls.