# Transparency in Windows 8 (Metro App)

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5, transparent

I am trying to make  transparent Grid but Text(or something else) on it not transparent. What i am supposed to do? And sorry for my English.

Comment: If you want to hide it, collapse it.  Don't just set its color to transparent.

Comment: No I've set opacity 0.9 so it's not a transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per an older question, the trick to allow a child element to override the opacity is to use a brush on the parent's background instead:

```
  <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
  </Grid.Background>
```

You can find more here: [How do you override the opacity of a parent control in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650576/how-do-you-override-the-opacity-of-a-parent-control-in-wpf)