# transparent background in windows store app

Tags: xaml, windows-store

i'm trying to implement windows store application with transparent background.
in my xaml i wrote:

```
<Page
x:Class="App4.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App4"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Transparent">
```

but the background is black

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding `Opacity` within your `Grid`?

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Background>
     <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
</Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Reference: [How do you override the opacity of a parent control in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650576/)